# No resource identifier found for attribute 'MvxBind' in package in Xamarin Android app

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, mvvmcross, xamarin-studio

I'm using Xamarin Studio v5.10.1 and Xamarin Android v6.0.0.34 and MvvmCross v3.5.1.

I keep getting this error message when I build the solution:

`No resource identifier found for attribute 'MvxBind' in package my.package`

I've seen all the question in stack overflow regarding this error but nothing helped.

Here is what I tried:

1. Clean everything and rebuild
2. Used `res-auto` instead of my package name
3. Upgrade to the latest Mono Android

It seems that the file `MvxBindingAttributes.xml` is not copied to the `Resources/Values` folder. I assume it is supposed to be extract from `Cirrious.MvvmCross.Binding.Droid.dll` but somehow it doesn't.

I also tried creating the `MvxBindingAttributes.xml` file myself in the right place. It fixed the compilation error but a runtime error complaining about the same thing (resource id's not found).

Comment: Did you install MvvmCross.StarterPack?

Comment: I am following the TipCalc example and it said to install MvvmCross Libraries. But after it didn't work I also installed the starter pack but it didn't help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK. I just checked. It doesn't seem like the NuGet actually installs MvxBindingAttributes.xml into the Resources\values folder. So you have to create it yourself:

The contents need to be this: https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/blob/3.5/Cirrious/Cirrious.MvvmCross.Binding.Droid/Resources/values/MvxBindingAttributes.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
  <declare-styleable name="MvxBinding">
    <attr name="MvxBind" format="string"/>
    <attr name="MvxLang" format="string"/>
  </declare-styleable>
  <declare-styleable name="MvxControl">
    <attr name="MvxTemplate" format="string"/>
  </declare-styleable>
  <declare-styleable name="MvxListView">
    <attr name="MvxItemTemplate" format="string"/>
    <attr name="MvxDropDownItemTemplate" format="string"/>
  </declare-styleable>
  <declare-styleable name="MvxExpandableListView">
    <attr name="MvxGroupItemTemplate" format="string"/>
  </declare-styleable>
  <item type="id" name="MvxBindingTagUnique"/>
  <declare-styleable name="MvxImageView">
    <attr name="MvxSource" format="string"/>
  </declare-styleable>
</resources>
```

### **EDIT:**

> This information is *not* valid for MvvmCross **4.x** where `MvxBindingAttributes.xml` is included in the ***MvvmCross.Binding*** package. This means, that it is no longer necessary to include this file yourself or through a NuGet into your project.

Comment: Please see my answer. I already tried this and got a different error. Also, it seems like the (NuGet is supposed to do this)[https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/blob/4.0/MvvmCross/Binding/Droid/MvvmCross.Binding.Droid.csproj#L163].

Comment: You are looking at the 4.0 branch there. One of the changes in 4.0 is that you don't need MvxBindingAttributes.xml anymore as it is compiled into the Bindings dll. This isn't the case for 3.5.1.

Answer (score 2):

Adding the MvxBindingAttributes.xml to the Resources/values folder in the solution worked for me.

https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/blob/3.5/Cirrious/Cirrious.MvvmCross.Binding.Droid/Resources/values/MvxBindingAttributes.xml

I am also using xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" in the axml file

Comment: This answer worked for me on the newer versions of MvvmCross. Chosen answer did not work for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

For me, my namespace in the XAML wasn't defined correctly...

I had:

```
xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/AndroidApp1.Resource"
...
local:MvxBind
```

But the namespace of my app (in project properties) was AndroidApp1.AndroidApp1 (its a PoC :)).

So when I fixed that - it all worked:

```
xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/AndroidApp1.AndroidApp1"
...
local:MvxBind
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I mistyped the package name in the android manifest. Ensure that your `xmlns:local` attribute in the *.axml* file match the package name.

**YOUR-PACKAGE-NAME** must be the same here...

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/YOUR-PACKAGE-NAME"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
```

and here

[image: Android Manifest]

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is real old but if you are having this error in Xamarin Studio version 6.1.5 and MvvmCross version 4.4.0 make sure you are creating a "Blank Android App" instead of a "Android App" This makes sure that no packages are included by default that will not play with with MvvmCross off the bat.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a reference from Manage NuGet Packages and from the search tap write MvvmCross.Bind and then install it.

Comment: Adding Nuget Package MvvmCross.Binding Worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I know it is old topic but I found another solution.
When you create new project remember to name core: name.Core and android app: name.Droid . It solved all my problems.